# Running testng in a loop by modifying global variables

Tags: java, automation, testng

I have a TestNG program that takes certain parameters as arguments from command line. TestNG is invoked programmatically. One of these arguments is "locale" which indicates either US or DE or ES etc. If i specify US it executes the test cases specified by the runner for US locale. If i sepecify "US,DE" it runs for US and DE. If i specify "ALL" it runs for all available locales provided in an enum.

Basically how i have coded it is:

```
foreach locale 
  set global locale variable to locale
  testng.run()
endfor
```

This works fine , but the problem is it creates multiple testng reports for each time testng.run is executed in the for loop. Is there a way to modify this such that it executes and reports as one big test suite i.e., One consolidated report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will do what you want but TestNG has a feature called Data Providers. First you define a data provider method:

```
@DataProvider(name="locale")
public Object[] createData() {
    return new Object[] {"US", "DE", "ES"};
}
```

You can then refer to the data provider in a test method, accepting its data as parameters:

```
@Test(dataProvider="locale")
public void doTest(String locale) {
    ...
}
```

The test method will be run once for each item supplied by the data provider. I've only used the analogous feature in JUnit so I don't know how TestNG renders the individual runs. In JUnit's Eclipse plug-in you get an additional level in the test result tree-view.

The data provider method can produce a two-dimensional array to provide several parameters at the same time. See the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) for details.

Comment: Thanks! This works. This gave me a heading of where to go from here.